# How to create single matrix chart using columns of multiple tables in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables

- Inventory: Products, Warehouse, I_Quantity
- Orders: Products, O_Quantity

I want to create a single Matrix chart in PowerBI that shows values of I_Quantity under warehouse column against each product and also shows O_Quantity (Which is from Orders table) as a separate column against each Product. (PS - I have joined both the table using Products column)

Example:

```
Warehouse  A           B           Total        O_Quantity
Products   I_Quantity  I_Quantity  I_Quantity   
A-1-234    50          40          90           1000
A-2-345    45          35          80           1250
and so on...
```

currently O_Quantity column displays values under Warehouse column and I don't want that. see below:

```
Warehouses A                     B                        Total
Products   I_Quantity|O_Quantity I_Quantity|O_Quantity    I_Quantity|O_Quantity
A-1-234    50         1000          40         1000       90         1000
A-2-345    45         1250          35         1250       80         1250
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your data model. Why A has Q_Quantity and B doesn't in the first row, due to A letter in the product name? Seems that you just need to unpivot your first table. You can do it for example with PQ. You can do it with a measures, but it's better to rearrange your table - this will allow you to avoid measure wrighting.

Comment: @Mik, I've edited my question for your better understanding. Hope you have the answer for what I am looking for.